# exe version of code shows error message when i try to close it

Tags: python, pygame

this code that i wrote runs fine in my ide and the exe version. but the problem arises when i try to close the program. it shows me this error(and yes, i've imported sys and used sys.exit() instead of quit().):

> File "source.py", line 77, in 
> File "source.py", line 41, in main
> for event in pygame.event.get():
> NameError: name 'quit' is not defined

my game is almost done, and this is the only thing that bothers me. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code that the error is reffering to?

Comment: If `source.py` doesn't contain `quit`, but the error message talks about it anyway, this could mean you 1) didn't save the file; and/or 2) didn't rebuild the exe after changing the code to use `sys.exit`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write pygame.QUIT instead of quit